# Displaying input character's binary value

Tags: c++, binary, ascii

I'm trying to understand why I keep getting an unexpected binary result. For example, if I were to write
`8`
I will get a result of
`00111000`
and not
`00001000`

I'm not trying to manipulate to get another result, I'm trying to see what the actual data is for my input and understand why it's giving that input.

I'm using C++ in visual studio with a platform of Win32.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    char cl;

    cout << "The minimum value of char is " << CHAR_MIN << endl;
    cout << "The maximum value of char is " << CHAR_MAX << endl;

    cout << "The storage size in byte(s) of a char is " << sizeof(cl) << endl;
    cout << "Input hexadecimal number in the data type of char for example a" << endl;

    scanf_s("%c", &cl, sizeof(cl));
    bitset < 8 * sizeof(cl)>charBits(cl);

    cout << "The converted binary value is " << charBits << endl;
    printf("The converted decimal value is% i \n", cl);
}
```

Comment: I didn't get it, why you have added `iostream`as well as `stdio` header file?

Comment: I'm not sure how this is related to the [assembly], [cpu-registers] and [microprocessors] tag, it seems like you're just trying to print a character as binary... Also, Why use `scanf_s` as opposed to `cin` or even `getchar`? Why the `printf` after all those `cout`s?

Comment: This was part of a lab and it's been sometime that I have not been looking at it until now, however I never understood the bitset part of this lab, it was still unclear to me. This is just part of the entire lab, I did not include the rest of the code, because it was repetitive for each datatype. We were using scanf, I believe we were focusing on the datatypes which will eventually lead us into assembly language. However, now Visual Studio said scanf was marked as deprecated, so I changed it to scanf_s

Comment: @Xvx fair enough, but I'd still suggest you remove all tags apart from [c++] and [binary]; After all, even though this will *eventually lead to assembly*, the actual question at hand is still irrelevant to assembly, really. I don't think `scanf` itself would be much of an issue with a character (though `getchar` would still be the simplest and best), but I'm sure using `scanf_s` shouldn't be much of an issue either.

Comment: Also, when you write 8, it gets the ASCII value that holds the character 8, which is 56 I believe. So your program is perfectly fine, you just need to look up the ASCII table.

Comment: Yup, I just checked the decimal value of `00111000` and it is 56. Here, I'd suggest you take a gander at the ASCII table in the future. http://www.asciitable.com/ If you want to get the actual number, change the format string in `scanf_s` from `"%c"` to `"%hhd"`.

Comment: So you enter the character '8' because scanf is configured with "%c".  But the character '8' has a value of 56 (hex 38) in the same way as character 'A' has a value of 65 (hex 41).  So if you want to see the bits of the number 8 then you can take the character you entered and subtract the value of '0': `bitset < 8 * sizeof(cl)>charBits(cl - '0');`  Then the value of the bitset will be 8 and it will do what you expect.  However, if you want to see the bits of the character '8' or 'a' or whatever character is actually entered then what you have written works well.

Comment: The bitset just converts a numeric value into binary for you.  You could write the conversion yourself (it isn't hard) but that's not the point of the lab - the point is for you to understand that all characters have a value.

Comment: Wow, yeah you're right about ASCII, it explains a lot. Oh snap yeah I got 00001000 when I wrote
```sizeof(cl)>charBits(cl - '0');```

Answer (score 1):

The value being input is an ASCII character, and you should convert that value to its corresponding number before printing. in ASCII, the letters 'a'-'f' have the range 97-102, 'A'-'F' have the range 65-70, and '0'-'9' have the range 48-57. So after getting your input, test its ASCII value with `if`'s and subtract accordingly like this:

```
// Subtracting 87 converts 'a' to 10 and 'f' to 15, the numerical representations
// of those hexadecimal values, which are then converted to binary by bitset.
if (cl >= 97 && cl <= 102)
    cl -= 87;
// Subtract 10 less again for the same reason above.
else if (cl >= 65 && cl <= 70)
    cl -= 55;
// Subtracting 48 from '0' converts it to the number 0 in memory,
// and subtracting 48 from '9' converts it to the number 9.
else if (cl >= 48 && cl <= 57)
    cl -= 48;
```

You'll notice that this breaks the decimal printing, so you should convert the number to decimal for printing like this `cout << static_cast<int>(cl) << endl;`.

Comment: A simple `static_cast<int>(cl)` may be better than using `to_string`. Also, I'd suggest you replace the magic numbers scattered throughout your code with character literals to make it easier to understand. _Also_, I see no reason to subtract in case of A/a-F/f Unless you want to find, for example, its position in the alphabet (In which case, could you tell why you're choosing to subtract by 10 less? Like subtracting 87 as opposed to 97?).

Comment: Subtracting 10 less from 'a' converts it to 10 in memory, the hex representation for 'a'. I added comments to show this. Also, yes, a cast is likely the better option here so I changed that.

Comment: Ah ok, I hadn't thought about it that way. Fair enough, you've earned my upvote ;). I'd still suggest you replace the magic numbers with character literals, but since you've already noted the ASCII values beforehand, this isn't absolutely necessary.